# How do I send a custom error message from Node, and display it with catch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

I'm trying to send a custom error message from node, receive it on the frontend, and display it.

On server I'm trying to do:

```
res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
```

And on client I'm doing:

```
try {
    const res = await axios.post(`${API_URL}/profiles/signup`, credentials)
} catch(err) {
    console.log("Sign up error:", err)
}
```

What I want is to get something like this in my console:

```
Sign up error: Something broke!
```

but I'm getting:

```
Sign up error: Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)
```

How do I access the custom message I'm sending?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an error with the help of Error()

```
throw new Error({code: 500, message: 'Sign up error: Something broke!'});
throw send your error to the catch block automatically.
```

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out:

```
console.log("Sign up error:", err.response.data)
```